# SSISDB Lost Password will not add into AG Group

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, ssis, database-administration

There is  SSISDB on a server where all the databases are in the Availability groups.

I have tried adding this to the AG ,but it errors asking for the password which is lost!.

I have also tried the following:

ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH 'some new password'.

This does not work and i get an error:

The current master key cannot be decrypted. If this is a database master key, you should attempt to open in the session before performing this operation.

How can I add the database into the AG without having the ssisdb password.

Comment: You don't add it until you know the password. Your question is akin to "how do I open this lock for which I don't have a key?" Security is doing what it's designed to do, keep your secrets safe (SSISDB can store passwords and credentials).  I'm afraid you have to tear down the existing SSISDB and add everything back in, this time keeping track of the password. Posting as a comment and not an answer because maybe someone knows an approach I don't.

Comment: Even if you forgo adding it into the AG, you are now aware of a resume generating event - you have a database that even though you are taking backups, you won't be able to restore in the event of a disaster. It's your responsibility to inform people above you and get this resolved before it harms the company/client.

Comment: Ah okay How would I rebuild SSISDB? I take it in case of a mess we can always restore back to the previous backup of SSISDB